# Can I use a generic protocol to describe a delegate in a non generic type?

Tags: swift, generics, associated-types

I'm trying to describe a delegate property with a generic protocol without making the class generic:

```
protocol ActionHandler: class {
  associatedtype Action
  func handle(_ action: Action)
}

enum SomeAction {
  case dismiss
}

class Foo {
  typealias Action = SomeAction
  //  Protocol 'ActionHandler' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
  weak var handler: ActionHandler?
  // Ideally some form of ActionHandler<Action>?
}

class Handler: ActionHandler {
  func handle(_ action: SomeAction) {
    switch action {
      case .dismiss:
        print("dismiss")
    }
  }
}

let handler = Handler()
Foo().handler = handler
```

I can instead replace the property by a closure, but I don't like this pattern as much, and I would have to do so for every method described in the protocol.

```
enum SomeAction {
  case dismiss
}

class Foo {
  typealias Action = SomeAction
  var handleAction: ((Action) -> Void)?
}

class Handler {
  func handle(_ action: SomeAction) {
    switch action {
      case .dismiss:
        print("dismiss")
    }
  }
}

let handler = Handler()
Foo().handleAction = handler.handle(_:)
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: No. Why can't the class be generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to make `Foo` generic, but you'll need a very good reason not to. Anyway, here's one way that is built on top of your closure approach - What if we wrap those closures in a type?

```
class AnyActionHandler<Action> : ActionHandler {
    var handleClosure: (Action) -> Void
    func handle(_ action: Action) {
        handleClosure(action)
    }
    
    init<ActionHandlerType: ActionHandler>(_ actionHandler: ActionHandlerType) where ActionHandlerType.Action == Action {
        handleClosure = actionHandler.handle(_:)
    }
}
```

Now if there are more methods in `ActionHandler`, you can just add it in this type, rather than adding them everywhere where you assigned to `Foo.handler`. `Foo` can just have

```
weak var handler: AnyActionHandler<Action>?
```

And assigning the handler looks like:

```
Foo().handler = AnyActionHandler(handler)
```

This `AnyActionHandler` type is called a "type eraser".

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. I wish I'd not have to type erase but that seems like the best option.